# Where can I find the autocorrect / user dictionary on the iPhone and how can I have a look into it?

Tags: iphone, ios, dictionary, autocorrect

I would like to have a look into my personal user dictionary built on typed words on my iPhone. From eHow's article [How to Edit Auto-Correct on the iPhone](http://www.ehow.co.uk/how_8477684_edit-autocorrect-iphone.html) I found the following location where it should be located:

```
/private/var/mobile/Library/Keyboard/dynamic-text.dat
```

But my iPhone is not jailbroken so I think I don't have a chance to open this file, right? (And if I jailbreak my phone the dictionary will be deleted…)

I also have the backup of my phone on my Computer. Is it possible to find the dictionary there? 
What are other ways to have a look into your personal autocorrect dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

You can view the files in iTunes backups of your iPhone using [iBackupBot](http://www.icopybot.com/itunes-backup-manager.htm). Open the software, choose your Backup, then sorted by Path find `Library/Keyboard/dynamic-text.dat`.

It's not possible to view the user dictionary directly from the device without jailbreaking. Jailbreaking does *not* delete the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer. I just downloaded iBackupBot. How can I sort the Backup by path? I also can't find the "Library" folder. Screenshot of the software is uploaded in imgur.com: [https://imgur.com/a/vH8ln](https://imgur.com/a/vH8ln)

Comment: @iMax Ah it seems to have changed a little since last I used it. What's in the ‘HomeDomain’ folder? I don't have a backup to test myself at the moment.

Comment: Thanks. I found a Keyboard folder in `"KeyboardDomain" > "Library" > "Keyboard"`. Inside is a file called "langlikelihood.dat". Inside the Keyboard folder there is also another folder called "CoreDataUbiquitySupport".     
I posted an image with the found databases again on imgur.com: [https://imgur.com/a/psBGp](https://imgur.com/a/psBGp)
So: I found something… **but I am not sure what I see** :)